# Short question about 'multilinearity' of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that this is true and I think it's called multilinearilty of a determinant: 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
z & x & c  \\
a+b & a+b & a+b \\
q & w & e  \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
z & x & c  \\
a & a & a \\
q & w & e  \\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
z & x & c  \\
b & b & b \\
q & w & e  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now my question is, is it also true if the $a+b$ were in a diagonal like so ?

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a+b & x & c  \\
f & a+b & g \\
q & w & a+b  \\
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
a & x & c  \\
f & a & g \\
q & w & a  \\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
b & x & c  \\
f & b & g \\
q & w & b  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

My intuition tells me that it isn't true but I just want to make sure.

Also, I would appreciate linking to more info on multilinearity like in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $a=b=1$ and set all other values to $0$. See what happens.

Comment: Right! So it works only if the values are in the same row or column.

Comment: Yes - this also (sort of) explains the name of the property. You can think of the determinant as a function of $n$ vectors (in two different ways) by making these vectors the rows or columns of a matrix and taking the determinant. This function is then linear in each of its $n$ arguments.